# Drawing RTF to bitmap using EM_FORMATRANGE message produces text with ugly black fragments

Tags: c#, cleartype

I need to draw a RTF text on a custom background. I am using an extended RichTextBox control as described for example [here](http://www.andrewvos.com/2008/05/23/draw-rtf-text-on-a-graphics-object-in-c/) to render RTF itself. This works fine if the graphics is associated with the screen. But when I use graphics created from a bitmap the cleartype fonts have ugly black fragments like the antialiasing does not blend the text with the background correctly (I draw the background first). What is the reason of this? And can it be somehow fixed?

Example of code producing an ugly bitmap:

```
private void CreateBitmap(string rtf, Rectangle bitmapRectangle)
{
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapRectangle.Width, bitmapRectangle.Height))
    {
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            gr.Clear(Color.Yellow);

            // extended RichTextBox control from www.andrewvos.com
            RichTextBoxDrawer rtbDrawer = new RichTextBoxDrawer();
            rtbDrawer.Rtf = rtf;
            rtbDrawer.Draw(gr, bitmapRectangle);

            bitmap.Save(@"c:\bitmap.png");
        }
    }
}
```

One more thing: Graphics.DrawString works fine and draws correctly anti-aliased text.

Comment: This is invariably a side-effect of not initializing the bitmap correctly.  "I draw the background first" is not sufficient evidence that you did so correctly, you have to post a snippet.

Comment: Aside from rather complicated way I draw the background I tried also simple Graphics.FillRectangle or Graphics.Clear, but the result was always same. Are these methods enough to correctly initialize the bitmap?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it looks like I was drawing the background on the wrong place. If I draw the background on a graphics created from a device context handle to which is the EM_FORMATRANGE message sent in RichTextBoxDrawer.Draw method, then the text is rendered correctly:

```
public void Draw(Graphics graphics, Rectangle layoutArea, Bitmap background = null)
{
    //Calculate the area to render.
    SafeNativeMethods.RECT rectLayoutArea;
    rectLayoutArea.Top = (int)(layoutArea.Top * anInch);
    rectLayoutArea.Bottom = (int)(layoutArea.Bottom * anInch);
    rectLayoutArea.Left = (int)(layoutArea.Left * anInch);
    rectLayoutArea.Right = (int)(layoutArea.Right * anInch);    

    IntPtr hdc = graphics.GetHdc();
    using (Graphics backgroundGraphics = Graphics.FromHdc(hdc))
    {
        // draw some background
        backgroundGraphics.Clear(Color.Yellow);
    }

    // rest of the method is same
}
```